# System.OutOfMemoryException' was thown after 10PM. I am not able to catch actual error

Tags: c#, multithreading, sockets, tcpclient

On server following software installed:

1. Windows Server 2012, SQL Server
2. Symentec Antivirus
3. Finger print reader based on Nginx, MS Sql Server DB

I am not able to find the error. Threads throws error System.Outofmemory and Server have 6GB free memory. Max data received by one socket is less than 4kb

```
class ServerModule
{
    TcpListener serverSocket;

    public void StartServer()
    {
        serverSocket.Start();
        while (true)
        {
            try
            {
                if (cmd == -1)
                {
                    break;// stop loop
                }
                Console.WriteLine("Listening");
                TcpClient tc= serverSocket.AcceptTcpClient();
                System.Threading.Thread obj_thread = new System.Threading.Thread(new System.Threading.ParameterizedThreadStart(ProcessData));
                obj_thread.Start(tc);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                ErrorLogger.LogError("StartServer::", ex);
            }
        }
    }

    public void ProcessData(object ob)
    {
        TcpClient tcp_socket = (TcpClient)ob;
        NetworkStream ns = null;
        try
        {
            ns = tcp_socket.GetStream();
            int num = 0;
            byte[] obj_data = new byte[tcp_socket.ReceiveBufferSize];
            num = ns.Read(obj_data, 0, tcp_socket.ReceiveBufferSize);
            tcp_socket.Close();
            tcp_socket = null;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ErrorLogger.LogError("ProcessData::", data_from_device, ex);
            if (tcp_socket != null)
            {
                tcp_socket.Close();
                tcp_socket = null;
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Close with exception");
        }
    } 
}
```

Comment: You don't need to wait for it to crash to find a memory leak. You can hook up a memory profile to your app and exercise it, you should be able to find the leak way before it crashes with an out of memory exception.

Comment: The code in the question does not in fact process the data. It obtains the stream, allocates a buffer, copies the bytes into the buffer and then just leave it for the garbage collector to collect later. Did you remove code / simplify the example?

Comment: [please read the help section about writing titles](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is throwing the `OutOfMemoryException` because of many-many-many threads being created in it. Look:

```
// in a infinite loop
while (true)
{
    ...
    // for each TcpClient
    TcpClient tc= serverSocket.AcceptTcpClient();
    // you create a thread!
    System.Threading.Thread obj_thread = new System.Threading.Thread
}
```

This is the worst thing you can do in your code. Your application starves because of tons of threads being concurrently trying to listen the `TcpClients`. Recommended number of threads in your application is equal to the number of cores on your server machine ([Managed Threading Best Practices](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1c9txz50.aspx)).

Your really should use some thread pooling, either yourself written (personally I don't recommend it) or already built in ones ([How to: Use a Thread Pool (C# and Visual Basic)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3dasc8as.aspx)).

If you are using .NET 4.5, use [Tasks library](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460717.aspx) to simplify your code.
Right now your application is unstable and error-prone.

If for somewhat reason you still think that you should have to create a `Thread` each time you are calling the `TcpClient` (which is completely wrong, as I think), you should read this manual:

[How to: Create and Terminate Threads (C# Programming Guide)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7a2f3ay4.aspx)

Comment: I have to log data from over 900+ gps/gprs devices. Reason for thread: Before data save, data is analysed and processed and it takes time. So each time socket accept ,a thread. is created. Worker thread doesn't take much time 0.20 - 1 milliseconds. Thread pool will slow downs entire system. Do i need to upgrade RAM. Currently its running fine with 400 gps device sending data and processor is 2%. All parameter are stable

Comment: Did you measure the performance with `TheadPool`? Did you reuse the threads? If `No` is the answer for any of the questions, you should investigate your problem more. Right now your system has too much threads to process simultaneously.

Comment: Going to try ThreadPool, will pass socket to pool. I will inform you

Comment: threadpool solved the problem, server running fine, problem resolved. Thanks.